# i8253 manual programming by direct signal input

Tags: microcontroller, timer, proteus, intel

I have a 8253 programmable interval timer and I want it to work in the Rate Generator (MODE 2). How can I achieve this using direct signal inputs to the chip?
I have attempted to write the control word to the RCW, then input the number N to the counter on D0-D7, and apply a signal to GATE, but it doesn't seem to work.
[image: My scheme]

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. We can't know what you really sent to the chip. The buffer is disabled and the bit pattern on bus does not select mode 2, so we really can't know if you succeed sending the things you said you tried to send.

Comment: That's how I'm doing it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC9q2YJV67I

Comment: Pins 1and 19 of the 74ls541 should be tied low. Read the 8253 datasheet for the bus timing requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read and write are active low.

You are not writing to chip but reading from it.

Comment: Could you provide further clarification? If I set the input WR to signal 1, isn't that how I write to the chip?

Comment: No, like I said, you are not writing to but reading from the chip.

Comment: @EpicMandM Do you see these bars above `RD` and `WR` (and `CS`)? They mean that these signals have inverted logic, so you need '0' to make them active. The data sheet will tell you this, too.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDHUiuSt8oA

Comment: However, regrettably, it fails to function as well.

Comment: You still are not writing to the chip. You have not selected the chip. Also why do you use the buffer like that? A real chip will fail to work of you update bus with the address you want to access and the operation to that address simultaneously. Please read the data sheet how the bus waveforms should look like when writing to the chip.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and thorough explanations! It's becoming much clearer now. I'm still learning and sometimes the intricacies of these operations can be a bit challenging. I truly appreciate your time and assistance!